# A variational inequality satisfied in a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, proof-explanation, convex-optimization

I'm trying to establish the existance of $u \in K \subset V$, a closed convex subset of vector space with an inner product, such that for a fixed $q \in V$:
$$(u-q,v-u) \geq 0 \quad \forall v \in K$$
The proof I'm reading proceeds as follows:

> Note that the inequality holds iff $\|u-q\| \leq \|v-q\|$. Since $K$ is a closed convex subset, there exists a unique element of $K$ that minimizes $\|v-q\|$, namely $u = P_Kq$ where $P_K$ is the projection of $q$ onto $K$.

This was a bit terse for me. Why does the inequality hold? From what fact does $u = P_Kq$ follow?

Comment: Puh, what is $q$?

Comment: my bad $q \in V$

Comment: You should note that $V$ has to be complete, otherwise the projection might not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in the first statement of the proof. The variational inequality proves the inequality in norms, but the converse simply doesn't hold. For example, in $\Bbb{R}^2$ under the dot product, take $u = (0, 0)$, $v = (0, 3)$, and $q = (1, 1)$. Then
$$\|u - q\|^2 = 2 \le 5 = \|v - q\|^2,$$
but
$$\langle u - q, v - u \rangle = (-1, -1) \cdot (0, 3) = -3 < 0.$$
I suggest finding another proof of this inequality.

But, as for your second question, if you can show that $\|u - q\| \le \|v - q\|$ for all $v \in K$ (and where $u$ is assumed to be in $K$), then you've found a point $u \in K$ that is of minimal distance from $q$. This, by definition, makes $u$ the metric projection of $q$ onto $K$.

EDIT: Actually, I have a proof of this inequality that I wrote up on hand:

> **Theorem:** Suppose $X$ is a real Hilbert space, and $C$ is closed, non-empty, and convex. Let $x \in X$ and $z \in C$. Then,
>   $$\langle x - z, c - z \rangle \le 0 \quad \forall \, c \in C$$
>   if and only if $z = p_C(x)$.

*Proof:* Suppose $z, c \in C$, with $z \neq c$. Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
\begin{align*}
f(\lambda) &= \|x - \lambda c - (1 - \lambda)z\|^2 - \|x - z\|^2 \\
&= 2 \lambda \langle x - z, z - c \rangle + \lambda^2 \|z - c\|^2.
\end{align*}
Note that this is a convex quadratic in $\lambda$.

Suppose that $z = p_C(x)$. When $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, we have $\lambda c + (1 - \lambda)z \in C$, hence $f(\lambda) \ge 0 = f(0)$. The minimum value of $f$ must be achieved at some $\lambda^* \le 0$. Thus,
$$0 \ge \lambda^* = \frac{-\langle x - z, z - c \rangle}{\|z - c\|^2} \iff \langle x - z, c - z \rangle \le 0.$$
Note that the final inequality also holds for when $c = z = p_C(x)$.

Conversely, suppose $z \in C$ such that $\langle x - z, c - z \rangle \le 0$ for all $c \in C$. Therefore, when $c \neq z$, $\lambda^* \le 0$. This implies that $f$ is increasing on the interval $[0, 1]$. Hence,
$$\|x - c\| = f(1) \ge f(0) = \|x - z\|.$$
As this holds for arbitrary $c \in C$, we have $z = p_C(x)$.

Comment: What is $K$ in your example?

Comment: $K$ is the closed, non-empty, convex set onto which we are projecting, as in the question.

Comment: You should specify it in your example. Otherwise it is incomplete.

Comment: @amsmath Actually, in my counterexample, there is no such $K$ (I thought you were referring to the second paragraph). My point was that the two inequalities were not equivalent; in particular, if the OP was trying to manipulate one inequality into the other, they were not going to succeed.

Comment: Of course they are not equivalent. But the points $u$ and $v$ are supposed to be in a closed convex set. However, in your example you can just choose the segment from $u$ to $v$ as $K$. Since one always can do that, your counterexample is actually valid without specifying $K$.

Comment: I wouldn't say "of course"; the way the proof reads to me is that there's a simple algebraic manipulation that turns one inequality to the other, that has been omitted due to how straight forward it actually is. When furnished with an appropriate set, and adorned with the appropriate quantifiers, this thing is actually true (see my proof), and thus there is no counterexample. I'm just trying to justify to the asker why this proof is insufficiently detailed, and reassure them that they're not missing something obvious.

Comment: I'd say saying "of course" is valid because it's geometrically obvious that this only holds if (and only if) $u$ is the projection of $q$ onto $K$. At least in finite dimensions.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you or I would have trouble proving the inequality, but the asker has looked at a (purported) proof, and has asked our help. I don't like to say "of course" the proof is wrong, or is misleading, or anything like that. It is the perogative of the asker, once the penny has dropped, to say the first "of course". In fact, on a given question, that's the point when I know my role as tutor is complete.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is incorrect. Consider $V = \mathbb R^2$ and $K = \overline{B}_1(0)$, $u=(0,0)$, $v=(\epsilon,1-\epsilon)$ for some small $\epsilon > 0$ and $q = (2,0)$. Then $\|u-q\|\le\|v-q\|$ and $(u-q,v-u) = -2\epsilon < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proof is missing an important detail: What we actually have is that for $u \in K$ and $q \in V$ the statement
$$ (u - q, v - u ) \ge 0 \qquad \forall v \in K$$
is equivalent to
$$ \|u - q \| \le \| v - q \| \qquad \forall v \in K.$$

The proof is given in the answer by Theo Bendit.

The second statement is just $u = \operatorname{proj}_K(q)$.